# Does ODBC require any run-time software beyond an .exe file to run against MySQL and ORACLE SQL?

Tags: c++, sql

I'm writing a software [under Windows] in C++ which later needs to be able to connect to both MySQL and ORACLE SQL. Now the software needs to be as simple for the user as possible.

Now I'm considering using ODBC.

If I use ODBC, does the software later need any additional drivers, or only during development? When I have the `.exe` file, do I need any additional software to have it run on any computer or simply the executable?

Comment: Off-topic, should go to StackOverflow; however, your question is perhaps operating system specific. On Linux you'll need some libraries. And you should show some code in your question.

Comment: I'll never understand the difference between stackOverflow and programmers... :/

Comment: StackOverflow is for implementation specific issues and help debugging. Programmers is for understanding how and why things work they way they do. You will often find caveats associated with the question you are asking, whereas SO tends to be just the answer to the question.

Comment: @xamiax - Unfortunately, the rules and administration aren't perfect and there are different interpretations, but over time and a few examples, you'll start to see the difference. I hope this doesn't discourage you from spending enough time on this site. We can't tell you to use or don't use ODBC, but if you want to know how to make this specific coding problem work, go to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: people still use ODBC? sheesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most ODBC drivers do not rely on additional software to be installed. The ODBC driver installation adds all of the components it needs. ***Oracle***, however, is different.

For Oracle, you will need the Oracle Client software to make the connection. You can find out more details on their page [Oracle ODBC Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-098976.html). While the page doesn't explicitly state that you need the client software, the [ODBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/odbcfaq-128251.pdf) does mention that it needs SQL*Net application layer (which is a part of the Client software).

**UPDATE**

A friend reminded me that there are 3rd party Oracle drivers that do not require any Oracle code. The examples he gave me do cost money, whereas the drivers from Oracle do not. I'll put links to them in the comments.

Comment: One set of 3rd party drivers you can get is [dbExpress Driver for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dbx/oracle/) and [dbExpress Driver for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbx/mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are mixing a variety of requirements and concepts and need to revisit your architecture.

1. A simple user application is NOT a function of the drivers you have! This is more about platform, UI design and usability tricks. You need to separate these efforts in your mind.
2. Just because your data has MySQL and Oracle doesn't mean that your GUI will also need MySQL and Oracle. You could have (1) a pre-processing step to combine data or (2) add an API layer that will make the database agnostic.

You shouldn't have your users access your database directly anyways. So why not create an API/services layer (like REST) and have your app access it that way. From there, the API layer can access any number of databases and you won't have any worries about drivers on the GUI side. It simply makes more sense to do it this way and minimizes potential pitfalls for your end users.